# Best solution to connect 3 external monitors to Dell XPS 15 9550

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, xfce, external-monitor, matrox

I am searching the web for a while and am confused. Hope you will help me in choosing the right solution.

I want to connect 3 external monitors (possible [Dell E2216H](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-e2216h-monitor/pd)) and am searching for the best adapter compatible with Xubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.4.6.

I am now in between [Matrox TrippleHead2Go DP edition](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/displayport/) or USB2 or USB3 adapter.

I do know that with Matrox I have to configure it first under Windows ([like described here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744124)), and what is puzzling me now - will it be easier\more stable setup that a bunch of USB adapters connected through USB3 active hub...

So if one have experience with the topic I would be glad to hear your thoughts. I am especially interested in USB adapter models that will work with Ubuntu.

P.S. Please feel free to ask any additional questions needed.

Comment: OK. here is additional info I can share with others.  USB is somehow tricki as pointed [here](http://plugable.com/2014/03/06/displaylink-usb-2-0-graphics-adapters-on-linux-2014-edition). It consumes your CPU power and lot's of cheapters might just not work on a stock system.

Comment: I have a DisplayLink USB adapter that I no longer use. (I used to use it when my primary computer was a laptop.) However, I did try out my USB device with the driver that DisplayLink recently developed for Ubuntu, http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu. I wasn't too thrilled with its performance. It rendered very choppy graphics doing basic stuff. It could have just been my system though. I have three monitors, but I use a desktop now with all three monitors connected to one ATI 5450 card, and I use a Chromebook (with Xfce Ubuntu crouton on it) for my computer on the go.

Comment: Jbrock - thanks for sharing. Seem like your CPU is a bit underpowered for such USB device, can imagine what it would be with compiz ;). I personally do think to go with Matrix or even external Thunderbolt box with full functional GPU inside...

Answer (score 0):

Was making experiments for a while and got the answer ready.

1. USB dongle will use a lot of CPU especially for FHD and above resolutions. As said, if there is a lot of moving\changing objects (letters, video, diagrams etc) that should be displayed through USB adapter this is not a solution in case of more than one display.
2. Matrox TrippleHead2Go DP edition will relay on your hardware (video adapter) and will not cost you anything in terms of performance (thus it will heat up some chips). As said if your internal video processor is able to handle needed resolution (do not forget of notebook's own display) you will be ok.
3. There are tow ways of slightly other approach:

   3.a Use external video card connected by DisplayLink

   3.b Use external video card connected by PCI-express
   I will not go through both of those ways as it is out of scope for this question.